# Can you define supremum of a set without using upper bounds in your definition?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Typically, in giving the definition of the supremum of a set, we assume the reader knows what upper bounds of a set are. Can supremum be defined without using upper bounds?

Comment: If you want to avoid the words "upper bound", they why not write $\sup X$ is the smallest number $a$ such that $x \le a$ for all $x \in X$?  Or is that not the question?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Would you not need to mathematically show what "smallest number" is?

Comment: Can you define what an elephant is without using the concept of animal?  I'm not sure your question actually makes sense.  The sup is a specific upper bound with a single additional criterion.  If you want to define it without using the words "upper bound" just describe the definition of "upper bound" in its definition.  If you want to define it without the *concept* of upper bound, of course you can't do that because a sup is nothing *but* the concept of upper bound.

Comment: @SamJaved The set of $a$ such that $x \le a$ for all $x\in X$ is closed, thus there is a minimal element.  The "smallest" such number is thus well-defined.  That being said, I think that fleablood made the point that I was attempting to make, but in a much clearer manner.

Comment: I think Xander's comment was very clear and correct IMO.  I would improve upon his definition more precisely thusly: A $\sup X$ is a number $a$ so that $a \ge x; \forall x \in X$ and for all $y < a$ then will always be an element of $x \in X$ so that $y < x$.  That does not use the words "upper bound" but completely uses the *concept* of "upper bound".

Comment: @fleablood Your second comment is what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, if you say so.... but I don't think my comment was particularly useful as I don't think the question is particularly meaningful.  An "upper bound" = "a number $a$ so that $a\ge x; \forall x \in X$" so simply replacing one phrase with another doesn't actually mean or signify anything.

Comment: @fleablood I see that my question was a little shortsighted and a better question would have asked to not use the phrase "upper bound" but that would also have been unnecessary as you showed by just replacing the phrase with a short definition

Comment: "the smallest number such FOO" = "x FOOs but for all y < x, y doesn't FOO" is basic and well-defined.  And "upper bound of X" = "a number, a, so that a >= for all x in X" is equally basic and well-defined.  I get the feeling you are trying to ask something significant but I don't see what it is.  The basic concept is "$a$ so that $a \ge x;\forall x \in X$" and you can't define sup without that concept and that concept is nothing more or less than "upper bound".  So I'm pretty firm that the answer to your question is "No".  And I feel kind of weird that you think I answered "Yes".

Comment: @fleablood Haha I don't believe that you answered yes to the question that you think I'm asking. I understand that supremum cannot be defined without using the concept of an upper bound (whether it's used in the definition explicitly (by name) or implicitly (by the quick definition you used). My question was about coming up with a definition for supremum that does not  explicitly use the words "upper bound" (which you have provided). Just a stupid mistake on my part where I failed to try to come up with your definition before asking the question.